# What is the evidence for a top-down Southern Strategy?

Tags: united-states, republican-party, racism

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_strategy), “In American politics, the Southern Strategy refers to a Republican Party electoral strategy to increase political support among white voters in the South by appealing to racism against African Americans.” I have really only encountered arguments for existence of this strategy in polemical contexts, and I am curious about the historical basis for the claim that there was such a strategy. The one source that is cited consistently is an infamous [1981 interview with Lee Atwater](https://www.thenation.com/article/exclusive-lee-atwaters-infamous-1981-interview-southern-strategy/). This is not a lot to go on for evaluating the motivations of the Republican Party as a whole, or those of its more prominent members. (For instance one could construct an unflattering narrative about the Democratic Party on the basis of [LBJ's racial attitudes](https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/lbj-voting-democratic/) or the fact that George Wallace [was doing well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Wallace#Democratic_presidential_primaries_of_1972_and_assassination_attempt) in the 1972 Democratic primary until he got shot.) What is the evidence that the shift in Southern states' voting practices is the result of an intentional Republican appeal to racist attitudes?

Comment: What are you suggesting with your mention of George Wallace and the attempt on his life?

Comment: @F1Krazy George Wallace was a prominent segregationist, so if one wanted to tar the Democratic Party with an allegation of racism, one could use his success as a Democratic candidate to do so.

Comment: Ah, so he was. I somehow completely misread the opening section of the article.

Comment: Have you attempted to do any independent research into this?  You imply that there is only one source to support the existence of a Southern Strategy, and that it is hard to find any others.  This is simply not true.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_strategy#References

Comment: Yeah, I read the article, but what I saw was people attributing motives (or more commonly, constructing a narrative straight from the electoral outcomes), rather than citing documentary evidence that sheds light on the motives of the actors. So I'm looking for evidence rather than mere assertion.

Comment: There are 110 references at the bottom of the Wikipedia article. They cannot all be made up, can they? Maybe the question is a bit too broad and should ask for evidence for a more specialized claim.

Comment: It's not entirely inappropriate to make inferences based on electoral patterns, I'm just looking for documentary evidence instead. (It's not a short article; do the article writers simply have an aversion to quoting documents... ?)

Comment: Note: questions and answers directly addressing "racism" or "race" at several  SE sites are frequently deleted; will leave it to you to determine the root cause of that fact. Wikipedia is at best a secondary resource. Emp. _"**a** Republican Party electoral strategy"_ not "**the**" strategy. The question links to an article that includes a primary resource (audio) of a deceased Republican Party strategist. Does the question ask for corroboration of the strategy disclosed by Lee Atwater; or the entire "top-down" explicitly stating the Party will use "racism" strategies to achieve its aims?

Answer (score 10):

The proof for the Southern Strategy is both deep and broad, but for a top-down strategy to do so that doesn't include Lee Atwater (Reagan's chief campaign strategist)? That's a bit harder.

First, there's the context. Lyndon Johnson signed one of the most controversial pieces of legislation in the history of our country: the Civil Rights act. Whether this was motivated by his own feelings, political gamesmanship or a combination, it's hard to say. But the South was abuzz over something so comprehensive as to destroy segregation as we know it.

We see it through the [publications](https://slate.com/news-and-politics/2008/02/william-f-buckley-rip.html) that have helped candidates rise to power both in the 60's and today.

We see it in actual papers [seized from the White House](http://www.cnn.com/2010/POLITICS/01/11/nixon.racial.strategy/index.html) during Watergate.

Goldwater's strategist [wasn't particularly secretive](https://www.theamericanconservative.com/2008/04/03/secret-origins-of-the-southern-strategy/) about it. A quote:

> Manion, the former dean of the University of Notre Dame Law School,
>   hoped to rally conservatives behind a Goldwater nomination, with the
>   expectation that when the nomination fell through, it would lead to
>   the formation of a new, conservative third party. Manion believed that
>   Goldwater could be enlisted to head the new third party’s ticket,
>   joined by an unnamed southern Democrat. …
>
> He was convinced that if Rockefeller won the nomination [in 1960],
>   conservatives within the GOP would break to form a new party. Although
>   some people around Manion spoke of running Orval Faubus of Arkansas
>   (best known for his opposition to school integration in his state),
>   Manion doubted the viability of a Faubus candidacy. For a while Manion
>   hoped that South Carolina Governor Ernest Hollings might lead a
>   southern revolt in the Democratic party, but in the end Hollings
>   refused to go along with the scheme. Although Manion did not support
>   forced racial segregation in the South, either in public or in his
>   private correspondence, he saw civil rights as an Achilles’ heel of
>   the Democratic party in the South. Anti-Communism and anti-big
>   government drove Manion’s politics, but he was willing to seize upon
>   dissension within the Democratic party, apparent in the formation of
>   the States’ Rights party in 1948 headed by South Carolina Governor
>   Strom Thurmond.

One of the big [movers and shakers](https://www.salon.com/2015/11/01/when_texas_fell_to_the_wingnuts_the_secret_history_of_the_southern_strategy_modern_conservatism_and_the_lone_star_state/) of the Goldwater campaign was fairly clear as well:

> During the first press conference for the Draft Goldwater Committee,
>   O’Donnell addressed the media and declared that the national
>   Republican Party ought to pursue an intentional Southern Strategy.
>   Because Goldwater was the only candidate who could successfully
>   execute such a strategy, the Arizona senator ought to be the party’s
>   nominee. “The key to Republican success,” O’Donnell argued, “lies in
>   converting a weakness into a strength and becoming a truly national
>   party.” The phrase “converting a weakness into a strength” meant
>   securing the once solidly Democratic South for a Republican candidate.
>   In his book about Goldwater’s campaign for the presidency, Suite 3505,
>   F. Clifton White cleared up any doubt over what O’Donnell meant by
>   including after that crucial phrase this parenthetical remark: “(the
>   paucity of Republican votes in the South).” At this revealing moment
>   in political history, O’Donnell had based his argument on a striking
>   admission. The Southern Strategy was an intentional maneuver on the
>   part of the party to win elections, and Goldwater, with his ability to
>   appeal to racist sentiments in the South, was seemingly the only
>   candidate who could deliver enough Southern votes to ensure a
>   Republican victory.

Goldwater himself didn't share these views, but he [wasn't loathe](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2001/03/26/he-knew-he-was-right) about exploiting them:

> Goldwater did not want to campaign for the segregationist vote; he had
>   even hoped that his personal opposition to discrimination would win
>   him the votes of black people. But he had believed all along that the
>   Southern white vote was basically conservative and potentially
>   Republican. Republicans, he told Georgia activists in 1961, ought to
>   stop chasing the votes of African-Americans and "go hunting where the
>   ducks are." And the ducks in 1964 turned out to be white Democrats in
>   revolt against integration.

One of [Nixon's strategists](http://www.nytimes.com/packages/html/books/phillips-southern.pdf) laid it out in documents, and later, a book. A quote from the interview about his book has him saying:

> All the talk about Republicans making inroads into the Negro vote is
>   persiflage. Even 'Jake the Snake' [Senator Jacob Javits of New York]
>   only gets 20 percent. From now on, Republicans are never going to get
>   more than 10 to 20 percent of the Negro vote, and they don't need any
>   more than that... but Republicans would be shortsighted if they
>   weakened the Voting Rights Act. The more Negroes who register as
>   Democrats in the South, the sooner the Negrophobe whites will quit the
>   Democrats and become Republicans. That's where the votes are. Without
>   that prodding from the blacks, the whites will backslide into their
>   old comfortable arrangement with the local Democrats.

We see it through the [actions](https://www.nytimes.com/2007/11/13/opinion/13herbert.html) of candidate Reagan.

We have two [RNC](http://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/content/article/2005/07/13/AR2005071302342.html) [chairmen](https://www.huffingtonpost.com/2010/04/22/michael-steele-for-decade_n_547702.html) not only acknowledging that it existed, but apologizing for their party's role in the Southern Strategy. These are men whose job it is to represent the whole of the Republican party, their spokesmen.

If there were just a couple of these sorts of things, we could call them coincidences. But there has to come a point when a rational human begins to see a pattern.

And if you don't believe that many high-ranking sources, there are [pages upon pages](https://books.google.com/books?id=MG6lKulbMk0C&printsec=frontcover&dq=%22southern%20strategy%22%20H.%20R.%20Haldeman&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiViOaHx8_fAhVM4oMKHcjuAE4Q6AEIKjAA#v=onepage&q=%22southern%20strategy%22%20H.%20R.%20Haldeman&f=false) of other documents you'd have to go to a library to see.

Comment: President Nixon’s actions can hardly be called those of a president seeking to inflame racial tensions. Nothing illustrates that better than the historic progress his administration achieved in ending the practice of segregating the races in “separate but equal” schools in the South. When RN took office in 1969, 68 percent of black Southern students attended segregated schools. Within 5 years, that # had been cut to 9 %. The Nixon administration did more in 1970 to desegregate Southern school systems than had been done in the 16 previous years, or probably since.”

Comment: In 1960, about 1 in 3 black voters voted for Nixon.
It wasn’t until 1964 that black support for the GOP fell off the cliff. Barry Goldwater’s vote against the Civil Rights Act of 1964 (which, ironically, was supported by larger proportions of Republicans than Democrats in both houses of Congress) drove black voter support for the GOP down below 10%. In the years since, it has rarely climbed above that mark & has never come close to the level Nixon received in 1960. “Southern Strategy” based on creating & then exploiting racial division is not only simplistic, it’s contradicted by the record

Comment: Saying 'it's more complicated than this' is not the same as saying all the above things did not happen.

Comment: @Aporter - What's important isn't what he did AFTER he got elected, it's what he did and what he promised (which buttons he pushed) in order to GET elected. His courting of segregationists like Strom Thurmond and the use of racial buzz-/dog-whistle- words like "states' rights" and "strict constructionists" show a conscious effort to woo the bigot population by appealing to that racism.

Comment: @Cardus the questions posed are: 1)What is the evidence that the shift in Southern states' voting practices is the result of an intentional Republican appeal to racist attitudes? and What is the evidence for a top-down Southern Strategy? Q) What does top-down mean to you?  A) top-down to me, means: that the entire or at least the vast majority of the Republican party were involved. I have provided more than enough evidence that demonstrates that, that was not the case.

Comment: @PoloHoleset as I mentioned in my answer, the notion that the use of "states' rights" and "strict constructionists" are things that would draw only votes from racists, is in itself absurd. Asserting that, is totally race baiting. Many people who are not racist believe(d) in the Founding principles of Federalism and the 10th Amendment

Comment: @Aporter - Except that those terms are most often used in that context, as a proxy for admitting racial animus. If they sweep up a couple hundred or so purely-motivated Hamilton fans along with the millions or bigots, that's a bonus, but marketing generally does not ignore the bulk of the market for the tiny niche.

Comment: @PoloHoleset but you keep ignoring the fact that in reality the "marketing strategy" didn't work, so that doesn't really hold water

Comment: (A) So, the fact that a strategy does not work means it was never an intentional strategy to begin with?  That's an interesting concept. Good to know Al Gore didn't run a losing "distance myself from unprecedented peace and prosperity" campaign, or Dukakis didn't make a mistake by putting on a helmet and climbing in that tank. Or Bush uttering "read my lips" was not an error. Or Taco Bell's awesome "our beef is made of beef, really!" campaign. Never realized strategists never make mistakes. (B) Up until today, race-baiting won the GOP the White House, all of Congress and SCOTUS.

Comment: @PoleHoleSet we could go back and forth on this all day, but the proof is in the pudding. The pudding being the vote on the 1964 Civil Rights Act. Only 6 Republicans in the Senate voted 'nay', 21 Democrats voted 'nay'. In the House of Representatives only 35 Republicans voted 'nay', while 91 Democrats voted 'nay'. That's 3x as many Democrats voting against. The only "top down political strategy" concerning race that came out of the 60s & continues today has been the 'strawman' built by the Democrats known as the "Southern Strategy".

Comment: @Aporter Let me pull out the dictionary definition of 'top down': "Used to refer to a situation in which decisions are made by a few people in authority rather than by the people who are affected by the decisions." I have shown that the strategists (those that propose and implement the 'strategy'/'direction' of the party), the campaign managers, and the candidates planned to use racial tensions towards their political advantage. Top-down doesn't mean 'everyone was in on it' or 'it worked perfectly'.

Comment: I appreciate the many sources, which I've just now had time to read carefully. I don't think you've presented evidence for a strategy that “appeal to racist attitudes” (OP). Presumably both Democrats and Republicans were trying to appeal to southern white voters, who were the majority (and among whom racism was presumably very prevalent). The question is whether there was an attempt to appeal to these voters with racist appeals.

Comment: @Aporter - It doesn't matter what percentages voted for or against, really. Democrats had huge majorities in the House, in the Senate, and they had the Presidency. They voted in overwhelming majorities for the passage, in both houses It was entirely in their power to stop the Civil Rights Act. Without support from the Democratic leadership and the White House, it doesn't get passed. So, feeling betrayed, the bigots left the party and were welcomed into the GOP. Strom Thurmond ring a bell? There's a reason he left, and there's a reason he had a place to go. Proof is, indeed in the pudding.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet that's NOT true. Yes the Democrats had the majority in both houses, but they did NOT have enough votes in the Senate(46) without the Republicans to get it through. If you look at all the Senators & Congressmen that voted against that Bill as Democrats a grand total of 2 became Republicans later on. STRAWMAN

Comment: @PoloHoleSet - actually upon second glance the Democrats didn't have enough vote in the House, without the Republicans either. They needed 208 only got 153 Democrats yea votes, Republicans had 136 yea votes. The % of Republicans that was for= 80% the % of Democrats = 63%, this whole narrative is a lie

Comment: @Aporter There's a classical statistical error problem here. A higher percentage of Northern Democrats voted for the Civil Rights Act than did Northern Republicans, and a higher percentage of Southern Democrats voted for the Civil Rights Act than did Southern Republicans. There just happened to be more Democrats in the south.

Comment: @Aporter Anyway, the Civil Rights Act was in 1964. Who voted for it doesn't say much about what was going on a decade or two later.

Answer (score -2):

Here is what we need to know about the so-called ‘southern strategy’: 
most southerners begin to identify as Republicans in the 1980's.

Most US House seats from the south become represented by the GOP in the 1990's.

At the state level, to cite a few examples, Mississippi, Alabama, and Louisiana didn't get Republican governors (for the first time since reconstruction) until the 1980's/early 90's.
Georgia didn't get a Republican governor until 2003 and Alabama's state house didn't turn Republican until 2010.

In fact, the Democrats controlled pretty much every southern legislature until about the mid-90's So this code language/strategy if it was one wasn’t very effective.

Somehow appeals regarding “state’s rights” and so forth became “racist”, because Republicans were pro small government with limited powers? I am pro Federalism and am white & native and the best man in my wedding was a black dude. So if I were alive and old enough to vote in the 60s does that mean I would be a racist? The labeling of the stance on this issue as racist is particularly troubling, considering the 10th Amendment is part of the Bill of Rights.

In addition, the demonization of stances on subjects regarding affirmative action, welfare, & so on, that I am pretty sure, that you can argue without being a racist; including being against affirmative action, just goes to show the level of which political parties, even back then will stoop to, to create narratives, and that is quite telling, in itself.

Did anyone seriously think segregation was going to make a comeback (legally) by the 1970's/80's? 
Even Paul Krugman’s check on reality in 'Conscience of a Liberal' (where the southern strategy was one of his main topics) acknowledged that most southerners wouldn't want segregation back even if the Feds allowed it.

So if that's the case, we must ask: how could this supposed strategy have so much influence when it is obvious that nothing much came of it?

Who would base their vote on getting virtually nothing? 
So were southerners voting based on race issues as implied?
 No. The data is fairly clear on this point:
 In the 1968 Presidential election for example. There was no ambiguity when it came to George Wallace (Democrat running as independent). So how did he do? He won 5 of 11 states in the old confederacy. The states he won were fairly rural. When you total up the votes of all 11 states, a more interesting picture emerges: it's almost exactly a 3-way split between Nixon (34%), Humphrey (31%), & Wallace (34%). 2/3 votes going for Democrats.
In other words: even at the height of the racial tension of the 60's, the vast majority of southerners wouldn't vote for a guy on race issues alone, if at all.

12 years later, Reagan won Mississippi (which Carter had won in 1976; along with almost the entire south). Reagan only got 1.72% more of the popular vote (49.4% of the total) in the south than Ford had gotten 4 years before. So it's clear a lot of the theories that surround this “strategy” are sketchy at best & if it really was a strategy, it was a poor one.

So ultimately my answer to the question, "What is the evidence that the shift in Southern states voting practices is the result of an intentional Republican appeal to racist attitudes?" is 2 part:

1)the evidence doesn't show enough of a voting shift to support that a theory existed that really did appeal to racist's attitudes

and

2) there isn't enough substantial evidence to really confirm that the strategy existed in more than a small handful of Republican's, potentially warped minds

Comment: how did I get a down vote on this immediately upon posting? Nobody could have read it in 2 seconds.

Comment: Your take on the 1968 election is interesting. A proponent of the Southern Strategy take (meaning Nixon was appealing to race issues) would see it as 34% Nixon + 34% Wallace = 68% of Southerners voting for race issues. But it's more complicated than that, since the other could be voting *against* that, and not all of either group might have had that as their main focus. Either way, "there was no ambiguity about it" is hardly true.

Comment: @Geobits you are correct I didn't think about it that way or in terms of when Wallace flipped on the segregation issue.

Comment: @Geobuts I also forgot to mention that  Nixon, in 1969 had instituted the 1st Affirmative Action program, called the Philadelphia Plan, which also pokes another hole in the theory

Comment: I believe the Philadelphia Plan was more about driving a wedge between African Americans and labor unions than anything else, to be honest.

Comment: @Geobits nearly everything in politics is a deception, so you are likely correct

Comment: Let's look at Presidential elections. 1956; Republican Eisenhower wins with a landslide, with only Missouri, Arkansas, Mississippi, Alabama, Georgia, South Carolina, and North Carolina going Democratic. Eight years later, LBJ sweeps the nation, but Georgia for the first time in history votes for a Republican president, and Arizona, Louisiana, Mississippi, Alabama, and South Carolina also go Republican, for several of those states for the first time since Reconstruction.

Comment: As for 1968; if Wallace was just a Democrat, why did he run against the Democrats? If you add Wallace's votes to Humphrey's, Humphrey would have won the election easily.